# Mocking the filesystem in C

Tags: c, mocking, cmake

I'm beginning to write a simple program in C, and would like to store the configuration on disk. To facilitate proper and correct unit testing, I'd like to do something to prevent the code under test actually reading from, and writing to the disk.

The configuration file format, for the sake of argument is YAML.

The API to the program would perhaps look something like:

```
myapp config
```

Would dump the whole config. (where there's a pre-existing configuration file/mock)

```
myapp config server
```

Would dump the server sub-key. (where there's a pre-existing configuration file/mock)

```
myapp config server=example.com
```

Would write the file, with the new value (whether *or not* there's a preexisting file)

Internally the configuration is simply a struct with a handful of keys, server host, server port, and a username from which to make some API calls.

I'm not at all worried about the position of the file on disk (directory) or the getopt/CLI parsing, simply how to mock network and filesystem operations are important to me for this learning exercise.

The question goes one step further, and that's to ask what techniques can be used to stub the *network*.

I'm more than likely going to be using cmockery, and libcurl.

One of my first thoughts was "maybe I should make a function like `read_configuration_file()` that I can mock in my unit tests", but I'm really not sure of the merit of this, the code in ruby to stub a filesystem might be so easy as:

```
File.stubs(:read).with('./configuration.yml').returns("---\nserver: example.com\n")
```

And, coming from this background, thinking in `C` terms, I am finding to be quite difficult.

I observe that not many people seem to test this stuff in C, or more particularly, if they do - they aren't writing about it.

**Note:** This isn't a homework problem, it just came off sounding a little like that after I wrote the whole thing, I'm actually just trying to learn C, coming from a Ruby background; you might notice some of my other questions on the topic of trying to do `C` "right".

Answer (score 0):

I think your premise

> "To facilitate proper and correct unit testing, I'd like to do
>   something to prevent the code under test actually reading from, and
>   writing to the disk."

is wrong.  You can always arrange to run the tests from a newly created empty directory, or whatever prearranged state you might want. How can this in any way affect the correctness of the tests?

Comment: Does it not ring true that it's not a unit test if it has any external dependencies? – And do you happen to know what about multiple tests with multiple possible inputs to test success, and failure conditions of file parsing, must then every individual unit test run in a sandbox with the correct data fixtures?

Comment: A unit test on a ruby program that used the filesystem would have all the same dependencies as a C program that uses it. Except for ruby.

Comment: Except the unit test in Ruby has a mocking library that means I can easily feed the input under test to my implementation.

Comment: If your program is meant to manipulate files, how is actually using a file-system an "external dependency"? You have to set up fixture anyhow; what difference does it make whether the test file is written to a physical file and read from there or artificially fed to the program? I think you're overcomplicating.

Comment: Only that running **my test *suite*** in a chroot limits me to one mocked file, that's a problem. Although as discussed with @TomDignan above, it might be workable to override a `which_configuration_file()` method in my code to feed mocked files to the program. It may also mandate that I use a chroot, or at least change the `pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see what the developers for CUNIT did, and see if you can avoid reinventing part of the wheel

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cunit/

Comment: Looks like the best bet is then "don't stub the file read" but rather "make sure your tests read a file you control" – that's what they're doing with `static FILE* temp_file = NULL;` - I just have to stub the function that determines which file to read, and let the stdlib do it's thing, I guess! Thanks for the link `CUnit` seems much more approachable than CMockery